# Cocos2d-x 2.1.5 win32 setup failed

Tags: cocos2d-x

I trying to install cocos2d-x on window , as saw a lot of tutorial are said just run build_win32.bat is ok , unless got some problem like “tests.exe doesn’t work anymore” or “Get data from file(C:\Windows\system32\fps_images.png) failed!” , however , both of common are not appear to me but other unknown error. could anyone help me ? below is the console output of my error :

```
/*
 * Check VC++ environment...
 */

/*
 * Building cocos2d-x library binary, please wait a while...
 */

Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1008]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 12/9/2013 10:30:38.
C:\cocos2d-x-2.1.5\cocos2d-win32.vc2010.sln : Solution file error MSB5009: Erro
r parsing the nested project section in solution file.

Build FAILED.

  C:\cocos2d-x-2.1.5\cocos2d-win32.vc2010.sln : Solution file error MSB5009: Er
ror parsing the nested project section in solution file.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.01
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1008]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 12/9/2013 10:30:38.
C:\cocos2d-x-2.1.5\cocos2d-win32.vc2010.sln : Solution file error MSB5009: Erro
r parsing the nested project section in solution file.

Build FAILED.

  C:\cocos2d-x-2.1.5\cocos2d-win32.vc2010.sln : Solution file error MSB5009: Er
ror parsing the nested project section in solution file.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.01
/*
 * Check the cocos2d-win32 application "TestCpp.exe" ...
 */

The system cannot find the path specified.
/*
 * Run cocos2d-win32 tests.exe and view Cocos2d-x Application Wizard for Visual
Studio User Guide.
 */

File not found - Resources
0 File(s) copied
File not found - Resources
0 File(s) copied
File not found - Resources
0 File(s) copied
File not found - Resources
0 File(s) copied
File not found - Resources
0 File(s) copied
File not found - js
0 File(s) copied
File not found - tests
0 File(s) copied
File not found - MoonWarriors
0 File(s) copied
File not found - WatermelonWithMe
0 File(s) copied
File not found - Published files iOS
0 File(s) copied
Can't find the binary "TestCpp.exe", is there build error?
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: version of your cocos2d-x ?

Answer (score 0):

Because the limited uploading size of google code, Emscripten lib and resources of WatermelonWithMe and CocosDragonJS were removed from releasing installing package.

In order to run Emscripten sample, you should
download Emscripten lib (http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&key=9b4efad421c8b103b2c94b796db973b0&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cocos2d-x.org%2Fnews%2F134&subId=d654e26afef9085d79aba37dfe97be28&v=1&libId=ecb08019-ccd8-442e-ba80-3415ca773619&out=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fkripken%2Femscripten&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F&title=Cocos2d-x%20%7C%20cocos2d-x-2.1.5%20released&txt=here&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_138019210527110)

put downloaded lib into COCOS2DX_ROOT/external/emscripten

And you should do following steps to run WatermelonWithMe and CocosDragonJS
download resources of WatermelonWithMe and CocosDragonJS
 http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&key=9b4efad421c8b103b2c94b796db973b0&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cocos2d-x.org%2Fnews%2F134&subId=d654e26afef9085d79aba37dfe97be28&v=1&libId=ecb08019-ccd8-442e-ba80-3415ca773619&out=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fminggo%2Fcocos2d-js-tests%2Ftree%2Ffor-cocos2dx%2Fgames&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F&title=Cocos2d-x%20%7C%20cocos2d-x-2.1.5%20released&txt=here&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_138019214388811
put downloaded resources into samples/Javascript/Shared/games

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution works for me.
Open cocos2d-win32.vc2010.sln or cocos2d-win32.vc2012.sln , delete the code below:
**GlobalSection(NestedProjects) = preSolution** to the end of this GlobalSection.